# useEffect constant post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to build a simple To-Do list web app with a MongoDB database. I seem to have the functionality working, but my useEffect hook keeps making an infinite amount of post requests to the server. I am confused as to why this is happening.

React code

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const payload = {
            roomkey: roomKey
        }
        async function getToDos() {
            const response = await axios({
                url: 'http://localhost:4000/api/choresdisplay',
                method: 'post',
                data: payload
            })

            setItems(response.data.items)

        }
        getToDos();

    }, [roomKey, items]) // render whenever roomkey changes (page load) or when user
                         // adds/deletes item

    console.log(items)
    function addItem() {
        /*setItems(prevItems => {
            return [...prevItems, inputText];
        });*/

        const payload = {
            item: inputText,
            roomKey: roomKey
        }
        async function addTodo() {
            const response = await axios({
                url: 'http://localhost:4000/api/chores',
                method: 'post',
                data: payload
            })
        }
        addTodo()
        setInputText("");
    }
```

Server side

```
userRouter.post('/chores', function (req, res) {
    const roomkey = req.body.roomKey;
    const newItem = new tdlModel({
        Item: req.body.item,
        roomKey: roomkey
    });
    newItem.save()
})

userRouter.post('/choresdisplay', async function (req, res) {
    const roomkey = req.body.roomkey;
    console.log(roomkey)
    tdlModel.find({ roomKey: roomkey }, await function (err, foundMates) {
        console.log(foundMates)
        if (err) {
            res.send({
                token: USER_LOGIN_FAIL
            })
        } else {
            console.log(foundMates);
            res.send({
                token: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                items: foundMates,
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are telling `useEffect` to rerun when `items` change, but then you change it within the `useEffect` itself. So you are creating an infinite loop. It seems your logic is fine without that dependency, so just remove it from the list:

```
    ....
    }, [roomKey])
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are changing a state (setItems) inside the useEffect and listening at changes on the same state (items), it's causing an infinite loop.

You need to either add a condition around you call or change you array of dependencies